# How to add unique image formats to Matlab's imread, and Matlab's drag and drop?

Tags: matlab, file, imread

We have a number of internal image formats which I process in Matlab.  I have read/write functions for all of them.  For specificity, consider the [TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) image format, for which there is a file exchange [image reader](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28276-read-truevision-targa-images).

Matlab has reasonable drag and drop support for image formats supported by [imread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html).

That is, you can drag an image from explorer, drop it on the "Workspace" pane, and Matlab will read in the image, and copy it into your workspace.

I'd like to be able to add drag and drop support, and imread support for TGA files.  (imread has nice autocomplete for filenames for instance, tga_read_image does not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting off from [Tommaso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632906/7328782), I created the following M-file on my MATLAB path:

```
function out = openics(filename)
img = readim(filename);
if nargout==1
   out = img;
else
   [~,varname] = fileparts(filename);
   disp(['assigning into base: ',varname])
   assignin('base',varname,img);
end
```

Dragging and dropping an ICS file onto MATLAB's command window shows the following on the command line:

```
>> uiopen('/Users/cris/newdip/examples/cermet.ics',1)
assigning into base: cermet
```

Check:

```
>> whos cermet
  Name          Size             Bytes  Class        Attributes
  cermet      256x256            65714  dip_image
```

Reading the code for `uiopen` (you can just type `edit uiopen`) shows that this calls `open` with the filename, which then calls `openics` with the filename and no output argument.

You can also type

```
img = open('/Users/cris/newdip/examples/cermet.ics');
```

to call `openics` and load the image into variable `img`.

<sub>NOTE 1: I'm using ICS because I don't have any TGA images to test with. ICS is a microscopy image file format.</sub>

<sub>NOTE 2: `readim` is a function in [DIPimage](http://www.diplib.org)</sub>

<sub>NOTE 3: This is cool, I had never bothered trying to drag and drop files onto MATLAB before. :)</sub>

Comment: What version of matlab are you using?  (I'm using 2017b).  Where is opencis on your path?  Very curious that I can't get this to work.

Comment: When I set a break point at the beginning of uiopen, it doesn't get hit when I drag a .tga file into my workspace.  (Again, using 2017b, or even 2016b)

Comment: @John: my bad, I said "workspace" when I should have said "command window". My MATLAB only has a command window, I close all the other bits because they don't interest me. :)   I use R2017a, but I don't think the behavior has changed in many years.

Comment: When dragging to the "workspace", the area that shows all current variables, `uiopen` is not executed for me either, it opens some Excel-like tool for an ICS file. When dragging to the editor everything is opened as a text file, but that makes sense. I don't know why the different behavior between the command window and the workspace window.

Comment: Okay, so, I can drag to the command window (cool!) and uiopen is getting called (cool!) but it's not putting the image into the workspace, it is just calling my opentga file, and not putting th eimage anywhere that I can see.....  Puzzling....

Comment: The path are all the directories you see when you type `path`. These are mostly set by toolboxes, but there'll be a user directory at the top of the list. You can add directories to the path using `addpath`.

Comment: Copy the structure of the function I wrote. Especially the part that says `assignin`.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think [this](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/open.html) is what you are looking for. Quoting the official documentation:

> **open name opens the specified file or variable in the appropriate
>   application**
>
> You can extend the functionality of open by defining your own
>   file-handling function of the form openxxx, where xxx is a file
>   extension. For example, if you create a function openlog, then the
>   open function calls openlog to process any files with the .log
>   extension. The open function returns any single output defined by your
>   function.

For example:

```
function opentga(file) 
    % Your logic for reading and, eventually,
    % displaying TGA files when drag and drop
    % or other opening events occur.
end
```

And here is a full working example directly taken from the link:

```
function opentxt(filename)
   [~, name, ext] = fileparts(filename); 
   fprintf('You have requested file: %s\n', [name ext]);

   if exist(filename, 'file') == 2
     fprintf('Opening in MATLAB Editor: %s\n', [name ext]);
     edit(filename);
   else
      wh = which(filename);
      if ~isempty(wh)
         fprintf('Opening in MATLAB Editor: %s\n', wh);
         edit(wh);
      else
        warning('MATLAB:fileNotFound', ...
                'File was not found: %s', [name ext]);
      end
   end
end
```

An alternative path consists in overloading the `uiopen` function, as shown in [this](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15294-drag-drop-for-user-defined-file-types) File Exchange release.

Comment: opentga works with the "open" command, which does solve some of my problems, (i.e. reasonable auto-filename completion).  But, it doesn't solve all my problems, i.e. the drag and drop functionality.  I have not tested overwriting uiopen but my issue with that, is it requires my users to carefully manage their paths, which they do not do, and rebel against vehemently whenever it is suggested.

Comment: That's curious. Using the example above, the automatic drag & drop loading works fine for me whenever i put a text file into the Matlab workspace.

Comment: For what concerns the paths management, in order to suppress any potential rebellion, you could tell your users to put the custom open function into a folder (a safe one, in the Matlab installation path for example), and register it with `addpath`. This will make it work no matter where they are located and they will just forget about it.

Comment: What version of matlab are you using?  The drag&drop is not loading my tga files (it thinks the tga is a text file, and isn't calling opentga).  I'm seeing this in both 2016b and 2017b.  If I set a breakpoint in uiopen, it never gets hit on a drag and drop for a .tga file (for me).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers address the "drag and drop" question.  They do not address the question of how to integrate a proprietary image format into `imread`.  This can be done fairly straight forwardly with the [`imformats`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imformats.html) command.

The issue of how/why it took me 3.5 years to figure that out will remain unanswered I'm afraid....  The feature has been around for 15+ years.